# SELECT Statement Combining Multiple Rows

Tags: sql

I am currently working with an audit log table similar to:

```
ID  |  EventTime           |  AccessID  |  AccessType  |  Status  |  Final
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 2013/02/10 01:01:01  |  NULL      |  123         |  335     |   OK
2   | 2013/02/10 01:01:01  |  985521    |  NULL        |  66      |   OK
....
41  | 2013/02/10 07:07:07  |  NULL      |  456         |  335     |   OK
42  | 2013/02/10 07:07:07  |  113228    |  NULL        |  66      |   OK
```

What I need to select is the `AccessID` and `AccessType` into one row, i.e.:

```
AccessID  |  AccessType
------------------------
985521    |  123
113228    |  456
```

The `AccessID` is always unique and are only available in the row where `Status = 66`. The `AccessType` is only available where the `Status = 335`.

The `EventTime` is always shared for status 335 and 66.

I have tried grouping the data by event time, using sub selects etc but haven't quite managed to get the end result I need.

**Additional Info**

There are approximately 100000 rows a day added.
For each EventTime there are approximately 40 rows all with different information (there are more columns than the example provided below)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select max(AccessID) as AccessID,  max(AccessType) as AccessType
from audit_log 
where Status in (335,66)
group by EventTime
```

Comment: might want to filter it out on Status 335 and 66 in case there are other values in there too.

Answer (score 2):

This should work too I think:

```
SELECT A1.AccessID, A2.AccessType 
FROM 
    (SELECT EventTime, AccessID FROM audit_log WHERE Status=66) A1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT EventTime, AccessType FROM audit_log WHERE Status=335) A2 
ON A1.EventTime=A2.EventTime
```

Might give better performance if there's an index on `status`. It did for me with a small test case, but might not with a larger set of data. The execution plan suggest lower cost though. I guess it depends on what indexes are available.